# Check if dictionary index is same as the value stored at that index python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, hashmap, key-value

How can i check if the dictionary index is same as the value stored in that index in python

for example:

```
my_dictionary = {3:3, 5:4, 6:2, 10:0, 19:1}
```

clearly we can see that at 2nd index the value stored is 2;
here we have to return True
but at first index we have the value 3;
here we have to return False

the final result should look like this:
{False , False, True, False}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Note that up to python 3.6 dictionary is unordered collection.

Comment: I think you mean for the final result to be `[False, False, True, False, False]`, not `{False , False, True, False}`.  You have five values in your dict and so should expect five values in the result, and the result can't be a set (`{...}`) because a set can only have one of each value (hence it couldn't have multiple `False` values).

Comment: The value 2 is at the 3rd index (0-based), not the 2nd index.

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate` over the dictionary's `values` and compare:

```
>>> my_dictionary = {3: 3,    5: 4,    6: 2,    10: 0,    19: 1}
>>> [i == v for i, v in enumerate(my_dictionary.values())]
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

Note that dictionary ordering is a little tricky and is not something that you usually want to code around or depend on too strongly.  In recent versions of Python, dictionaries preserve ordering according to when their keys were added, but you can't `sort` a dictionary like you can a list, and in older versions of Python dictionaries were considered completely unordered.

Consider using an `OrderedDict` or even a list of tuples to store this data instead.